# What steps can I take to figure it out how an exisiting application is created and designed in Salesforce?

Tags: managed-package

I am tasked to research how an existing application was built in Salesforce?

What steps can I take to figure out the current app was created and designed to work? I need to effectively communicate to others what can and cannot be done for future additions and enhancements.  Please note I am not able to ask the previous person that worked on the application.

Comment: What are you asking really? You could look at the code or look at the Schema to see how it is built

Comment: Hi Zach. Im new to this. Im having a hard time explaining my question. I just updated it.  Do you understand what I am asking now?

Comment: I think I understand but not really sure how to advise. I would say just start looking around the application. Look at the Apex Code and Triggers. If the Application uses Visualforce then look at those and do the same for Lightning Components if it is a Lightning App. Look at the Process Builder, Workflows. Just start working with the app and you will start to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on the assumption that this is a Managed Package, you can go to Setup > Create > Packages, click on the Managed Package, and click View Components. This will show you everything involved in the package. However, you'll still have to figure out a good place to start. I would start with items that have no dependencies, as those are the "starting points" for the application. Next, look at the items that were included by those starting points, and figure out what they do. Keep following the pattern until you've worked it all out. Write documentation for every single component until you've got it all mapped out.

Keep in mind that even though this *sounds* simple, you're going to be in for a rough ride. Deciphering a single component can easily take a few hours (think of an Apex Class with 3000 lines of code), and there can easily be up to 10,000 items in an application. It might take you a day to document, or it might take a few months. There's really no way to know until you start digging in to it. For example, one job I got in to, I convinced my boss that we needed to optimize this application they had, and it took me a total of about five months to document and optimize the code (it was probably close to 35,000 LOC when I started, with over a dozen custom objects and hundreds of fields).

Comment: Thank you. It is a managed package. I'll try this approach also.